# Sorting arrays numerically by object property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

How would you sort this array with these objects by `distance`, so that you have the objects sorted from smallest distance to biggest distance?

```js
[
  { distance: 3388, duration: "6 mins", from: "Lenchen Ave, Centurion 0046, South Africa" },
  { distance: 13564, duration: "12 mins", from: "Lenchen Ave, Centurion 0046, South Africa" },
  { distance: 4046, duration: "6 mins", from: "Lenchen Ave, Centurion 0046, South Africa" },
  { distance: 11970, duration: "17 mins", from: "Lenchen Ave, Centurion 0046, South Africa" }
]
```

Comment: The pattern for [sorting by properties](/q/2466356/4642212) numerically is `myarray.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)`. To sort [lexicographically](/q/1129216/4642212), use `a.from.localeCompare(b.from)`. To sort descending instead of ascending, negate the return value (e.g. `b.distance - a.distance` instead of `a.distance - b.distance`). To sort [numeric _strings_](/q/979256/4642212), optionally use `Number`. To sort by [multiple properties](/q/6913512/4642212), chain other sorts with `||`, e.g. `b.someNumber - a.someNumber || a.someString.localeCompare(b.someString)`.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), eg

```js
myArray.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
```

The `sort()` method accepts a *comparator* function. This function accepts two arguments (both presumably of the same type) and it's job is to determine which of the two comes first.

It does this by returning an **integer**

- Negative (less-than zero): The first argument comes first
- Positive (greater-than zero): The second argument comes first
- Zero: The arguments are considered equal for sorting

When you're dealing with numeric values, the simplest solution is to subtract the second value from the first which will produce an ascending order result.

Comment: Alternative, using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment): `myArray.sort(({ distance: a }, { distance: b }) => a - b);`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon that's not an _alternative_ so much as it is the same thing but 10 characters longer syntactically. Potato / tomato