# How can I sort this JSON using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sorting

This my JSON file data.

```
{"434762882136408065":{"hacksilver":1500,"lastDaily":"06/15/2018","username":"Bader56"},"419738969530433548":{"hacksilver":"10009000","lastDaily":"NOT COLLECTED","username":"Robotos"}}
```

And i want it to log users by richest to not richest
like

> 1. ROBOTOS: 10009000
> 2. Bader56: 1500

i tried

```
Object.keys(userData).forEach(user => {
        console.log(userData[user].username+': '+userData[user].hacksilver);
    });
```

but its logging Bader at first place, Also i tried `.reverse()` but it the same if there third person here

Comment: Of course it gives you Bader first as you just load the array. Try sorting it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889040/401499

Comment: example please? im beginner a this stuff

Comment: Check the link I pasted - you've got example there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `sort()` the array first.

Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array. use `sort()` to reorder the array. Use `forEach` to loop thru the sorted array.

```js
let userData = {"434762882136408065":{"hacksilver":1500,"lastDaily":"06/15/2018","username":"Bader56"},"419738969530433548":{"hacksilver":"10009000","lastDaily":"NOT COLLECTED","username":"Robotos"}}

Object.values(userData).sort((a, b) => b.hacksilver - a.hacksilver)
                       .forEach(o => {
                            console.log(o.username + ': ' + o.hacksilver);
                       })
```

---

If your nodejs does not support `Object.values` you can use `Object.keys` as:

```js
let userData = {"434762882136408065":{"hacksilver":1500,"lastDaily":"06/15/2018","username":"Bader56"},"419738969530433548":{"hacksilver":"10009000","lastDaily":"NOT COLLECTED","username":"Robotos"}}

Object.keys(userData).sort((a, b) => userData[b].hacksilver - userData[a].hacksilver)
                     .forEach(o => {
                          console.log(userData[o].username + ': ' + userData[o].hacksilver);
                     })
```

Doc: [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: I got Object.values is not a function, BTW im using nodejs

Comment: what version of Node.js?

Comment: 6.11.2 on Ubuntu

Comment: @Josha I added another block of code using `Object.keys`

Comment: @Josha Anyway, Node v7+ supports `Object.values`

Comment: Now i got undefined

Comment: Yes. will basically sort the users from the higest hacksilver to the lowest

Comment: Im using external file, btw userData is the variable

Comment: Yes, you can this on dynamic values.

Comment: in data, `hacksilver` has values both as numbers and strings. Cast it to `Number`

Comment: @SudhanshuVishnoi how?

Comment: Are you able to `console.log(userData)`?

Comment: `fs` is async in nature (i think). So make sure that you already have the `userData` before you do the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the original object to array, so you could use `sort` method on it, and then sort it by any criteria:

```
const dataObj = {"434762882136408065":{"hacksilver":1500,"lastDaily":"06/15/2018","username":"Bader56"},"419738969530433548":{"hacksilver":"10009000","lastDaily":"NOT COLLECTED","username":"Robotos"}};

// convert object to array
const dataArr = Object.keys(dataObj).map(key => dataObj[key]);

// sort it by hacksilver value
const sorted = dataArr.sort((a,b) => {
    return Number(b.hacksilver) - Number(a.hacksilver) 
});

console.log(sorted);
```