# I want to order this array according to appeared number

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This is my array:

```js
const suggestion = [
  {
    name:"apple",
    appeared: 3
  },
  {
    name:"orange",
    appeared: 1
  },
  {
    name:"potato",
    appeared: 0
  },
  {
    name:"cake",
    appeared: 2
  }
]
```

But I want to show like this:

```js
const suggestion = [
  {
    name: "potato",
    appeared: 0,
  },
  {
    name: "orange",
    appeared: 1,
  },

  {
    name: "cake",
    appeared: 2,
  },
  {
    name: "apple",
    appeared: 3,
  },
];
```

How is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting arrays in javascript by object key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889006/sorting-arrays-in-javascript-by-object-key-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```js
const suggestion = [ { name:"apple", appeared: 3 }, { name:"orange", appeared: 1 }, { name:"potato", appeared: 0 }, { name:"cake", appeared: 2 } ]
let check = suggestion.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.appeared - b.appeared;
});
console.log(check);
```