# Javascript sort objects in array by first column smallest number to largest

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some data which I need to sort using the first column of each object.

The project uses Angular / Typescript but it's still JS.

Here's how the data looks:

```
[
    {
        time: 1000.189,
        other: 100 
    },
    {
        time: 1023.189 ,
        other: 105 
    },
    {
        time: 999.189,
        other: 100  
    }
]
```

So the above should look like this:

```
[
    {
        time: 999.189,
        other: 100  
    },
    {
        time: 1000.189,
        other: 100 
    },
    {
        time: 1023.189,
        other: "105 
    }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: These objects don't have columns. There is no first column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting arrays numerically by object property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889006/sorting-arrays-numerically-by-object-property-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const array = [
  {
    time: 1000.189,
    other: 100
  },
  {
    time: 1023.189 ,
    other: 105
  },
  {
    time: 999.189,
    other: 100
  }
]

const result = array.sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time);

console.log(result);
```

result =
[
{
time: 999.189,
other: 100
},
{
time: 1000.189,
other: 100
},
{
time: 1023.189 ,
other: 105
},
]

this works in Angular/Javascript

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sortByColumn(colname){
  return array.sort((a,b)=>a[colname]-b[colname])
  }

const array = [
    {
        time: 1000.189,
        other: 100 
    },
    {
        time: 1023.189 ,
        other: 105 
    },
    {
        time: 999.189,
        other: 100  
    }
]

const orderSorted = sortByColumn('order')
const timeSorted = sortByColumn('time')

console.log(orderSorted)

console.log(timeSorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.array.sort((a, b) => a['time'] - b['time']);
```